# Find the missing value

Tags: logical-deduction, number-sequence

find the value of  **1 + 7** from the following.

```
3   +   3   =   3

5   +   4   =   4

1   +   0   =   3

2   +   3   =   4

3   +   4   =   5

1   +   7   =   ?
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Answer is**

> 5

**Explanation**

> 3   +   3   =   3 (no of letters in Six)
> 5   +   4   =   4 (no of letters in Nine)
> 1   +   0   =   3 (no of letters in One)
> 2  +   3   =   4 (no of letters in Five)
> 3   +   4   =   5 (no of letters in Seven)
> 1   +   7   =   5 (no of letters in Eight)